# throwing an instance of std::length_error, example requires boost

Tags: c++, boost, tree

This is my first c++ project, so there might be a beginner failure. Still have to learn a lot.

I am modeling trees (real outdoor trees) by fitting connected cylinders with the point cloud library. In my real scenario I detect about 3000 cylinders, which I want to store into a tree (informatics tree) structure with two levels.

I build up parent <-> child relations, if end point and start point of two cylinders coincidence. I start with the root cylinder and detect its children. For every child this is also performed recursively. As long as a cylinder has only one child, I add it to a so called segment with a vector of cylinders. If the childs children size is also 1, the grandchild is added to the same segment and so on. If a cylinder has more than one child, the current segment stops and for every child a new segment is created. All segments have also parent and child information so I can iterate though the tree in both directions.

I have set up a minimal running example to reproduce the error. Instead of 7 parameter cylinders my Test cylinders have only a start int and an end int. The header and cpp file:

TestCylinder.h

```
#ifndef TESTCYLINDER_H
#define TESTCYLINDER_H


class TestCylinder
{
public:
int start;
int end;
TestCylinder(int a, int b);
virtual ~TestCylinder();
protected:
private:
};

#endif // TESTCYLINDER_H
```

TestCylinder.cpp

```
#include "TestCylinder.h"

TestCylinder::TestCylinder(int a, int b)
{
    start = a;
    end = b;
}

TestCylinder::~TestCylinder()
{
     //dtor
}
```

The segments (they represent a branch part or stem part between two branching sections). Parent segment is referred to with a pointer, the child segments are stored in a vector:

TestSegment.h:

```
#ifndef TESTSEGMENT_H
#define TESTSEGMENT_H

#include "TestCylinder.h"
#include <vector>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

class TestSegment
{
public:
    TestSegment(TestCylinder cylinder, boost::shared_ptr<TestSegment> parent);
    TestSegment(TestCylinder cylinder);
    TestSegment();
    virtual ~TestSegment();
    std::vector<TestCylinder> getCylinders();
    boost::shared_ptr<TestSegment> getParentSegment();
    std::vector<TestSegment> getChildSegments();
    bool addCylinder(TestCylinder nextCylinder);

protected:
private:
    std::vector<TestCylinder> cylinders;
    std::vector<TestSegment> childSegments;
    boost::shared_ptr<TestSegment>  parentSegment;
};

#endif // TESTSEGMENT_H
```

TestSegment.cpp:

```
#include "TestSegment.h"

TestSegment::TestSegment(TestCylinder cylinder)
{
    cylinders.empty();
    cylinders.push_back(cylinder);
}
TestSegment::TestSegment(TestCylinder cylinder, boost::shared_ptr<TestSegment> parent)
{
    cylinders.empty();
    cylinders.push_back(cylinder);
    parentSegment = parent;
}
TestSegment::~TestSegment()
{
}

std::vector<TestCylinder>
TestSegment::getCylinders()
{
    return cylinders;
}

boost::shared_ptr<TestSegment>
TestSegment::getParentSegment()
{
    return parentSegment;
}

std::vector<TestSegment>
TestSegment::getChildSegments()
{
    return childSegments;
}

bool TestSegment::addCylinder(TestCylinder nextCylinder)
{
    TestCylinder endCylinder = cylinders.back();
    int x1 = endCylinder.end;
    int x2 = nextCylinder.start;
    if(x1==x2)
    {
        cylinders.push_back(nextCylinder);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And the tree class, which builds up the tree structure and provides some methods to iterate through the segments/cylinders:

TestTree.h:

```
#ifndef TESTTREE_H
#define TESTTREE_H
#include "TestSegment.h"

class TestTree
{
public:
    TestTree(std::vector<TestCylinder> cylinders_in);
    virtual ~TestTree();

    /*
     * Getters and Setters
     */
    TestCylinder&
    getRootCylinder ();
    void
    setRootCylinder (TestCylinder rootCylinderNew);
    boost::shared_ptr<TestSegment>&
    getRootSegment ();
    void
    setRootSegment (boost::shared_ptr<TestSegment> rootSegmentNew);


    void addChildCylinders(TestCylinder& currentCylinder, TestSegment& segment);
    std::vector<TestCylinder>
    getChildCylinders(TestCylinder& currentCylinder);
    std::vector<TestSegment>
    getSegmentList ();
    std::vector<TestCylinder>
    getCylinderList ();

protected:
private:
    std::vector<TestCylinder> cylinders ;
    boost::shared_ptr<TestSegment> rootSegment;
    std::vector<TestSegment> getChildSegmentsRecursively(TestSegment parent);
};

#endif // TESTTREE_H
```

TestTree.cpp

```
#include "TestTree.h"


TestTree::TestTree(std::vector<TestCylinder> cylinders_in)
{
    cylinders = cylinders_in;
    TestCylinder rootCylinder = cylinders.at(0);
    TestSegment root(rootCylinder);
    rootSegment = boost::make_shared<TestSegment>(root);
    addChildCylinders(rootCylinder,*rootSegment);
}

TestTree::~TestTree()
{
    //dtor
}


std::vector<TestCylinder>
TestTree::getCylinderList ()
{

    std::vector<TestCylinder> cylinders;
    std::cout << "GetCylinderList before getSegmentsList" << "\n";
    std::vector<TestSegment> allSegments = getSegmentList();
    std::cout << "GetCylinderList after getSegmentsList" << allSegments.size()<<"\n";
    for(std::vector<TestSegment>::iterator it = allSegments.begin(); it!= allSegments.end(); ++it)
    {
        TestSegment segment = *it;
        //std::cout << segment.getSegmentCylinders().size();
        cylinders.insert(cylinders.end(),segment.getCylinders().begin(), segment.getCylinders().end());
    }
    return cylinders;
}

std::vector<TestSegment>
TestTree::getSegmentList ()
{
//    std::cout<<"GetSegmentList rootsegment size :"<< rootSegment->get.size()<<"\n";
    return getChildSegmentsRecursively(*rootSegment);
}

std::vector<TestSegment>
TestTree::getChildSegmentsRecursively(TestSegment parent)
{

    std::vector<TestSegment> allSegments;
    allSegments.push_back(parent);
    for(std::vector<TestSegment>::iterator it = parent.getChildSegments().begin (); it != parent.getChildSegments().end (); ++it)
    {
        TestSegment child = *it;
        std::vector<TestSegment> children = getChildSegmentsRecursively(child);
        allSegments.insert(allSegments.end(),children.begin(),children.end());
    }
    //std::cout << "TestTree geChildSegmentsRecursively" << parent.getChildSegments().size()<< "\n";
    return allSegments;
}


void TestTree::addChildCylinders(TestCylinder& currentCylinder, TestSegment& segment)
{
    std::vector<TestCylinder> children = getChildCylinders(currentCylinder);
    if(children.size()==1)
    {
        TestCylinder child = children.at(0);
        if(segment.addCylinder(child))
        {
        addChildCylinders(child,segment);
        }
    }
    else if (children.size()>1)
    {
        for (std::vector<TestCylinder>::iterator it = children.begin (); it != children.end (); ++it)
        {
            TestCylinder child = *it;
            boost::shared_ptr<TestSegment> seg_ptr = boost::make_shared<TestSegment>(segment);
            TestSegment childSegment (child, seg_ptr);
            if (childSegment.getParentSegment() == rootSegment)
            {
                std::cout << "TestTreeCpp::addChildCylinders, rootSegment is parentSegment \n";
            }
            addChildCylinders(child,childSegment);
        }
    }
}


std::vector<TestCylinder>
TestTree::getChildCylinders(TestCylinder& currentCylinder)
{
    std::vector<TestCylinder> children;

    for (std::vector<TestCylinder>::iterator it = cylinders.begin (); it != cylinders.end (); ++it)
    {
        TestCylinder cylinder = *it;
        if(currentCylinder.end == cylinder.start)
        {
            children.push_back(cylinder);
        }
    }
    return children;
}


/*
 * Getters and Setters
 */



TestCylinder&
TestTree::getRootCylinder ()
{
    TestSegment root = *rootSegment;
    return root.getCylinders().at(0);
}


boost::shared_ptr<TestSegment>&
TestTree::getRootSegment ()
{
    return rootSegment;
}

//void
//TestTree::setRootSegment (SegmentModel rootSegmentNew)
//{
//    rootSegment = rootSegmentNew;
//}
```

The main function, just creating 6 connected cylinders and calling the tree with this list:

```
int
main (int argc,
      char** argv)
{

    // ------------------------------------
    // -----Load Cherry 1             -----
    // ------------------------------------
    std::vector<TestCylinder> cylinders;
    TestCylinder cyl(0,1);
    cylinders.push_back(cyl);
    TestCylinder cyl2(1,2);
    cylinders.push_back(cyl2);
    TestCylinder cyl3(2,3);
    cylinders.push_back(cyl3);
    TestCylinder cyl4(3,4);
    cylinders.push_back(cyl4);
    TestCylinder cyl5(3,14);
    cylinders.push_back(cyl5);
    TestCylinder cyl6(14,15);
    cylinders.push_back(cyl6);

    std::cout << cylinders.size() << "\n";
    TestTree tree (cylinders);
    std::cout << tree.getCylinderList().size() << "\n";
}
```

Building the tree might work, the following error occurs when calling the getCylinderList function:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  vector::_M_range_insert
Aborted (core dumped)
```

[Possible dublicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892649/terminate-called-after-throwing-an-instance-of-stdlength-error) was not helpful (for me), as I dont add or remove items while iterating.

Comment: Awful lot of code here.  Can you burn this down to something simpler and self-contained?

Comment: Will be difficult to make it simpler, as I think I already removed unnecessary functions from my main project. Can make every variable public and thereby get rid of getters and setters though. By self contained you mean put everything in one file and also get rid of the headers?

Comment: By self contained I mean:  http://sscce.org/

Comment: Will update code tomorrow in one file.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that TestSegment returns vectors by value, e.g. in TestSegment::getChildSegments. That means, you make a copy of the vector.

Now, in getCylinderlist you are calling std::vector::insert (which is the function that is mentioned in the error message of the exception) with the parameters segment.getCylinders().begin() and segment.getCylinders().end(). But these two calls to getCylinders do not return the same vector, but rather individual copies of each. So what you're essentially saying is

```
std::vector< TestCylinder > c1 = segment.getCylinders();
std::vector< TestCylinder > c2 = segment.getCylinders();
cylinders.insert( cylinders.end(), c1.begin(), c2.end() )
```

c1 and c2 are not the same, this is why the code fails.

The same problem arises with TestSegment::getChildSegments.

To solve this, you should return the vectors by const&.

Hope that helps.

Comment: A small side note (unrelated to the problem):  
  
The calls to cylinders.empty();  are not necessary and probably not what you want:  

- a std::vector is always empty after creation  
- std::vector::empty() just tells you whether the vector is empty, it does not modify the vector. The function you're looking for is probably std::vector::clear

Comment: Thanks for both useful comments. Havent uploaded my code though and already left my office, so I will continue tomorrow.